# Prolog file manipulation

Tags: file, prolog, predicate

I use `swi prolog`, I have a file like this,

```
yeni(a,b,c).
yeni(d,s,w).
```

I try to make a new list which occur predicate column. Such as

```
[a,d] 
[b,s]
[c,w]
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

load the file with the predicates, then load the file with your code.

to get a list with the lists of the predicates you could use the findall/3 predicate:

```
answer([L1,L2,L3):-
  findall(First, yeni(First,_,_),L1),
  findall(Second, yeni(_,Second,_),L2),
  findall(Third, yeni(_,_,Third),L3).
```

if you dont want to load the files manually, you can load one of them when you load the other like this:

:-consult(theOtherFile).